# How to update Login Info

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax enabled login form, which makes an ajax call to the server to login.  If successful, it sets the Session object with the username.  Then when it completes,  the OnSuccess event calls a partial view update which then shows the user name.

This works fine in VS. However, when deployed it does not.  I think the issue is that the Session is not getting updated fast enough for the second ajax call to be able to see it.  If I do a page refresh, then the username IS updated.

Is there some other way I should be doing this?  The only thing I can think of is make a database call to see if the user is logged in, instead of relying on the Session Object.

This is the Partial view:

```
<ul id="LoginLinksPartial">


@{ var customer = (NTC.PropertySearch.Models.Customer)Session["Customer"];}

@if (customer!=null)
{
        @customer.DisplayName
        @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Account")

}
else
{
    <ul>
        <a onclick="openLoginWindow()">Login</a>
        <a onclick="openRegisterWindow()">Register</a>
    </ul>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: client does not have a cookie to give you yet, your still on the same instance of http request as you was for login, I.E   client has not sent a session in its header yet.  This would be on the next request, hence the reason why refresh works

Comment: Yes, but I am using the Session object on the Server, so it seems it ought to be available.

Comment: not available to the client  server creates session --> send to client --> client sends session to server <-->  server client handshake.  Your case  server creates session ---> sent to client -->  client has not made a new request, so wont send in header -- result, no handshake

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I see your point.  Any suggestions?

Comment: don't do login in a popup if possible, and just create a normal login page, this will post, then send to page user was on, when access was denied.   or alternative is to reload the window, when login popup is closed.

Comment: I would much prefer that, but client has requested a popup so that the user does not lose data already entered in (Shopping cart type app)

Comment: thats understandable, but generally, when a new user visits a store, you create a session,  this is anom shopper,  this session ID is then used for the shopping basket, if user then logs in, you simply update the basket rows with new session.  If user then presses checkout, then everything will still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put as an answer so question can be resolved:

Client has not yet sent session back to server in order to create the session handshake.

recommendation in this instance is that ALL shoppers have a session when first visiting the website, if login occurs ( within popup )  the session is simply updated with the users REAL ID, and if needed, the basket rows are also updated with the new session ID  or User ID.